# NiFi's ConsumeKafka_2_0 supporting JAAS SASL with ScramLoginModule

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I've gone through [ConsumeKafka_2_0](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka_2_0/) documentation. However, it's not clear how to configure Kafka consumer with JAAS SASL specific to ScramLoginModule. I tried to follow the steps provided for PlainLoginModule provided in [additional details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka_2_0/additionalDetails.html) page. NiFi throws error saying

> Failed to construct Kafka Consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a JAAS file with content like:

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="kafkaclient1"
  password="kafkaclient1-secret";
};
```

Set the system property in nifi's bootstrap.conf like:

```
java.arg.16=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/kafka_client_jaas.conf
```

Then in the processor you need to add a user defined property with the name "sasl.mechanism" and set the value to "SCRAM-SHA-256".

If that doesn't work please provide the entire stacktrace of the error from nifi-app.log and show the configuration of the ConsumeKafka_2_0 processor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Bran. However, I was wondering why can't we provide jaas configuration in one of the user defined property to the ConsumeKafka_2_0 processor?

Comment: You might be able to add a user defined property named "sasl.jaas.config" and put the jaas entry as the value, have not tried it before

Comment: If adding "sasl.jaas.config" works on processor level, I can connect to multiple secure Kafka clusters. Let me try it out.

Comment: if you are using Scram you will still need to add the "sasl.mechanism" property as well because otherwise the mechanism will default to GSS

Comment: Yes. That's true

Comment: The NiFi docs don't mention anything about the sasl.mechanism property.  I had a similar problem with PLAIN and setting that fixed it.

Comment: in latest releases there is a first class property for "SASL Mechanism" so you do not need to add a user defined property anymore - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.11.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafkaRecord_2_0/index.html